# Make Knockout observable apply instantly?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a section of my page bound to a Knockout Viewmodel. When I click a link it loads some data and displays it a little farther down. I want to display a little loading img while it goes out and loads the data then hide it when it is complete. I have the following code (stripped down to show important parts). The Ajax call is **NOT** async, it was set to false for other code someone else is using so I cannot change it. The problem is the "self.Loading(false)" doesn't get fired until the ajax call is complete, so it doesnt appear to show up at all. If I switch the ajax call to async it works as intended. So I am wondering why the Ajax call is blocking the observables change since it is called before it, shouldn't it fire immediately. Is there a way to force it to trigger immediately.

HTML:

```
<a data-bind="click: GetInfo" href="javascript:;">
     <img data-bind="visible: Loading" src="myimg.jpg" alt="Loading" />
</a>
```

KO:

```
 self.Loading = ko.observable(false);
 self.GetInfo = function () {
    self.Loading(true);
    AjaxCall().done(function (data){
       self.Loading(false);
    }
 };
```

Comment: Just as an anecdote, the last time I saw a web application that was built on non-async XHRs, it was unsalvageable and had to be rewritten from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observable and the DOM are likely being updated immediately, but you can't see it because the browser probably doesn't get around to drawing the screen. The request is blocking the redraw because... it's non-async. This is the exact reason you should *not* make non-async requests.

As a workaround you could try to force the event loop to spin once by using `setTimeout` with a 0 timeout to run your horrible sync request after the observable change, but in all seriousness, just fix your request to be async. Browsers are not guaranteed to do anything (including running any loading animations) when your code is blocking.

Comment: Thanks, yah I personally am not a fan of sync requests either, I believe it was set up originally to get a knockout bind to wait until the data was loaded because it was binding to nothing and then changing causing weird flickers, but that problem is easier to fix than this one. Never knew sync blocked redraws thought it just blocked your top level code. I'll see if it possible to get it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a data-bind="click: GetInfo,valueUpdate: 'keyup'" href="javascript:;">
    <img data-bind="visible: Loading" src="myimg.jpg" alt="Loading" />
</a>
```

Comment: wtf does valueUpdate have to do with click events

Comment: For the sake of completeness  I tried it and it indeed does not work, thanks though.